# Elements of a partial order that bound above a given element

Tags: order-theory

Consider a partially ordered set $(A,\le)$, an element $a\in A$, and a set of elements $B\subseteq A$ with $b\ge a$ for all $b\in B$, such that any maximal chain in $(A,\le)$ that includes $a$ must contain at least an element from $B$. In other words, $B$ is a set of "upper bounds" of $a$.

For example, in the partially ordered set of subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$, $(\mathcal P(\{1,2,3\}), \subseteq)$, $\{2\}$ would be bounded by 
$\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$.

Does this set of elements have a standard name? Does this concept have some interesting known properties?

Comment: See if https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order) has any bearing on what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you mean to see if the wikipedia article defines what I'm looking for, or to see if the concept of Lattice gives me what I'm looking for?

Comment: Have a read and see if it offers any clarity.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that condition in the definition. This is also related to your previous comment. I’m on the phone now, I’ll fix the question asap

Comment: I've edited the definition to add that elements from $B$ must be created than $a$. In light of this, regarding your first comment, $B=\{\emptyset\}$ is not an instance because $\emptyset\not\supseteq \{2\}$. For the others, $B=\{\{2\}\}$ is correct, and so is $B=\{1,2,3\}$, but $B=\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$ is not because $\{3\}$ is not greater than $\{2\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the statement "going up, following any chain of elements comparable with $a$, you'll stay 'under' $B$ for a while but will eventually encounter an element from $B$". What about the poset $(\mathcal P(\{1,2,3\}),\subseteq)$ with $a=\emptyset.$ I believe the set $B=\{\{2\},\{3\},\{1,3\}\}$ satisfies your condition, right? Now $C=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ is a maximal chain in $\mathcal P(\{1,2,3\},\subseteq),$ but how does it encounter $B?$

Comment: You're right. In fact the definition I gave didn't capture the intuition of what I was looking for. I've edited the question to define what I'm looking for just in terms of... of what I'm looking for XD

Answer (score 0):

{ x : a <= x } is called the up set or upper set of {a}.
It is notated by a small up pointing arrow in front of a.

{ x : some a in A with a <= x } is called the up set or upper
set of A, written by small up pointing arrow in front of A.

Simular, in the down direction, are the down ward sets.

Comment: I've changed the question to better reflect what I was looking for thanks to @bof's comment. In any case, the definition present in the previous question was not simply about the set of all the elements above $a$. I was looking for a set of elements that is sufficient to bound $a$ from above. intuitively the whole upper set of $a$ is an instance of this, yes, but that's not in general what I needed.

Comment: The set B which you want to describe could be called a cofinal set up a.

Comment: A “cofinal set”? you please elaborate editing the answer?

Comment: Wikipedia is a good place to look for math stuff.  Cofinal means finishes together.  C subset A is confinal to A when for all a in A, some x in C with a <= x.